# Creating Tabs with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will create tabs dynamically. Below is how the function will work:

```
function create_tabs(array_var, target_element){
  /* array_var will be separated with comma
  /* target_element will be appendning the final data in that elemenet
}
```

so if I use the above function like below:

```
create_tabs('First, Second, Third', 'any_element_class');
```

if should append the element with class "any_element_class" with the following data.

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li class='tab-link current' data-tab='first'>First</li>
    <li class='tab-link' data-tab='second'>Second</li>
    <li class='tab-link' data-tab='third'>Third</li>
</ul>

<div id='first' class='tab-content current'></div>
<div id='second' class='tab-content'></div>
<div id='third' class='tab-content'></div>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: why cant refer this https://webdesignerhut.com/create-simple-jquery-tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a bit late but still another approach: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55qdmxma/)

```
function create_tabs(array_var, target_element){
var array = array_var.split(", ");
$(target_element).append("<ul class = 'tabs'></ul>");
$.each(array,function(i){
  $(target_element+ ' ul').append("<li class='tab-link' data-tab='"+array[i] +"'>"+  array[i] +"</li>")
});
$.each(array,function(i){
  $(target_element).append("<div id='"+array[i]+"' class='tab-content'></div>");
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the first parameter as array:

```
var array_var = ['first', 'second','third'];
create_tabs(array_var, '#any_element_class');
```

then loop over it in your function:

```
function create_tabs(array_var, element){
//...loop over array
$(element).append("<li class='tab-link' data-tab='"+array_var[i]+"'>"+array_var[i]+"</li>")
//
}
```